# How to identify a database as valid model?

Tags: sql, database, identity

Im having trouble identifying my databases as correct and valid version of my model. I have a GUID-id for my model I could use, but where do I put it? I dont want an entire table with only one row for this GUID. Is there any metadata-repository for databases (SQL Server 2008) or is there any other methods of identifying databases except their names? I could name the database to my model-GUID but it doesnt seem right...

The scenario is like this: I have a Entity Framework-model and I identify it by a GUID. I let the user pick a database-connectionstring and now I want to verify that its a valid database (which has been created from my app). I want to do this every time the app starts just to be sure. What Im doing now is checking that a certain table with a certain name exists but thats not good enough. I want to be 99% sure.

Edit: I would prefer to set this value from the DDL-script which is already setting up the database and I want to be able to get it from a SqlCommand in ado.net.

Comment: What's the problem with using an *entire table*? It would be more portable than some vendor-specific metadata facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [Extended database property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx)

In script:

```
USE preet;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'myVersion', 
@value = N'999-abc-123-nop';
GO
```

and

[image]

In the UI

[image]